# Manipulating Python import order precedency

Tags: python

As per my reserach on the topic, when we import a Python module, Python searches for the module in following order:

1. Built in Python modules
2. sys.path entries (current working directory + PYTHONPATH environment variable)
3. Some installation specific default folders (don't know that these are, possible site-packages etc?)

In this flow, can we manipulate this order somehow so that Python looks for a specific folder before checking current working directory? I'm specifically trying to achieve this in the context of a wsgi application.

Comment: This should only matter if you have two modules with the same name; and the solution could just be to rename one of them.

Comment: @kaya3 that is exactly my case, I have 2 versions of same package installed, and want to use one of them in a specific environment

Comment: @kaya3 here I explained the case in detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60449533/aws-lambda-django-app-deployed-with-zappa-python-import-precendecy

Comment: I think if you're using `pipenv` or `virtualenv` for your project then the solution should be through that, rather than working around it. The whole purpose of a virtual environment is to be able to use different versions of Python and/or libraries for different projects, so I'd be very surprised if there's no way to set up a virtual environment with the right version of this module, using those tools.

Comment: @kaya3 a very particular case pushed me to search for a solution in this manner. The tool we use for deployment builds packages locally, and then deploy them. Here the problem happens if we build on a mac / windows and upload to lambda. So I need the same version of a module in both environments, but compiled in different environments.

Comment: I really think you should give the sys.path a try after reading the comments here because you could just decide for every manner to change the code according to where the needed module is at, maybe change the code explicitly the way I described or to add an if, else statement (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm not so sure about changing the **order** of importing because, in my opinion, the order depends on how the language itself is written **but** what you can do is this maybe-

```
sys.path = ['/path/to/application/app/folder'] + sys.path
```

which will allow you to add firstly the module that you created to the path array.